# How to restrict couchbase access to only localhost

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase and would like to restrict the access to only localhost. 
Any help to point to correct document would be helpful, i tried to find the info in couchbase site, could not find.

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091                0.0.0.0:*                LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60168        127.0.0.1:8091           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8091        127.0.0.1:60168            ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 1):

Currently Couchbase does not have internal access controls at the IP level. [Bucket authentication via SASL](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/security/security-inside-server.html) is available but you will need to tune connection access via your firewall solution. Couchbase provide a list of ports that are required to be open in the [security outside Couchbase](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/security/security-outside-server.html) section of the documentation. If you set your policy to deny by default and open those ports you will have achieved what you are looking for.

I should mention that  it is not recommended to run your application on the same machine as Couchbase as it severely limits the flexibility to scale all parts of your stack independently.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Adam said, I might even go a step further and create a private network to run the Couchbase cluster in and then only open that network up to the application server. This way, when you add a node to the cluster to scale later on, it inherits the protection from the network layer. I say this as depending on how you do the server's firewall it could become difficult to maintain over time and usually that is when security gets lax. So if you can, set the ACLs at the network level.

Also, like Adam said do not run the app on the same node as Couchbase in production if you can help it. You will get resource collisions most likely. It is just a bad idea in general regardless of the DB usually.